# What if the OP can't reproduce anymore the behavior?

Tags: discussion, support, unanswered-questions

I've stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40160590/5077154) where,  after several "it should work as it is" comments,  the OP added that, for some strange reasons, now it all works and he would update the question as soon as the issue happens again.

The question still appears as "unanswered" but I feel that, at the moment, no one apart from the OP can make it meaningful again.

What is the appropriate action to take?

1. suggest to the OP in a comment to close it and open another if the issue reappears
2. flag it in some way
3. other

Comment: There is a close reason for *"a problem that can no longer be reproduced"*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question has now been closed as:

> *This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.*